# Compute: $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\int\limits_{0}^1 e^{\{nx\}}x^{100}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Can anyone help to compute this limit, please?
$\{nx\}$ denotes the fractional part of $nx$. 
Tried to replace $nx$ by another variable and write an entire integral as a sum of integrals: $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\int\limits_{i}^{i+1} $$
but it seems not to work out.

Comment: What is "the fractional part of nx"? I've never heard this term before.

Comment: @NathanielB: the fractional part of $x$ is $x\pmod{1}$, i.e. $x-\lfloor x\rfloor $.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative approach. We have $$I=\int_{0}^{1}e^{\left\{ xn\right\} }x^{100}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}e^{\left\{ xn\right\} }x^{100}dx
 $$ $$\stackrel{y=nx}{=}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{(k+1)}e^{\left\{ y\right\} }\left(\frac{y}{n}\right){}^{100}dy
 $$ then by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) exists some $z_{k}\in\left[k,k+1\right]
 $ such that $$I=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{z_{k}}{n}\right)^{100}\int_{k}^{(k+1)}e^{\left\{ y\right\} }dy
 $$ and since $e^{\left\{ x\right\} }
 $ has period $1$ $$ I=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{z_{k}}{n}\right)^{100}\int_{0}^{1}e^{y}dy=\left(e-1\right)\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{z_{k}}{n}\right)^{100}
 $$ now if we take the limit we have a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), so $$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{1}e^{\left\{ xn\right\} }x^{100}dx= & \left(e-1\right)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{z_{k}}{n}\right)^{100} \\
 = & \left(e-1\right)\int_{0}^{1}x^{100}dx=\color{red}{\frac{e-1}{101}}.
\end{align}$$
**Addendum:** I realized that this approach works for any periodic function with period $1$. So it is easily generalizable.

Comment: (+1) I really like this elementary approach. Bravò, Marcò :D

Answer (score 10):

We have that $e^{\{nx\}}$ is a $\frac{1}{n}$-periodic function and its mean value over a period is given by $(e-1)$.

By the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) (think to the Fourier series of $e^{\{x\}}$) it follows that:

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}e^{\{nx\}}x^{100}\,dx = (e-1)\int_{0}^{1}x^{100}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{e-1}{101}}.$$

---

We do not really need it, but the explicit Fourier series of $e^{\{x\}}$ is given by:
$$ e^{\{x\}}=(e-1)+2(e-1)\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2\pi m x)-2m\pi \sin(2\pi m x)}{1+4m^2 \pi^2}$$
and the $m$-th term of the series is bounded by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4m^2\pi^2}}$ due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
Additionally, for any $h\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have
$$ \left|\int_{0}^{1}x^h \sin(2\pi n x)\,dx\right|\sim \left|\int_{0}^{1}x^h \cos(2\pi n x)\,dx\right|\sim\frac{1}{\pi n} $$
for large $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is it posible to explain the solution in layman terms, please? Unfortunately, I do not have any background in Fourier series.

Comment: @O.F.: that is unfortunate, but roughly speaking, $e^{\{nx\}}$ is a fast-oscillating function with mean value $(e-1)$. Since $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{100}\sin(nx)\,dx = 0$ (the same with $\cos(nx)$, and that can be proved by integration by parts) only the contribute given by the mean value actually contributes to the final limit.

Comment: How can you type so fast

Comment: @AmanRajput: I have an army of monkeys (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) that turns out to be helpful, sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{\braces{nx}}x^{100}\,\dd x}
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{101}}\int_{0}^{n}\expo{\braces{x}}x^{100}\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

With [Stolz-Ces$\mathrm{\grave{a}}$ro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{\braces{nx}}x^{100}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{101} - n^{101}}\pars{%
\int_{0}^{n + 1}\expo{\braces{x}}x^{100}\,\dd x - \int_{0}^{n}\expo{\braces{x}}x^{100}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm] = &\
{1 \over 101}\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{100}}
\int_{n}^{n + 1}\expo{x - n}x^{100}\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

Integrating by parts:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{\braces{nx}}x^{100}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm] = &\
{1 \over 101}\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{%
\bracks{\expo{}\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{100} - 1} -
{100 \over n^{100}}\int_{n}^{n + 1}\expo{x - n}x^{99}\,\dd x}\tag{1}
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\quad\mbox{Note that}\ds{\quad%
0 < \verts{{1 \over n^{100}}\int_{n}^{n + 1}\expo{x -n}x^{99}\,\dd x} <
{\expo{}\pars{n + 1}^{99} \over n^{100}}
\stackrel{n\ \to\ \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\quad}
\\[4mm]
\mbox{such that ( see (1) )}\ds{\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\ds{\pars{%
{100 \over n^{100}}\int_{n}^{n + 1}\expo{x - n}x^{99}\,\dd x} =
\color{#f00}{0}}}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

---

$$
\mbox{Then ( see (1) ),}\quad
\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{\braces{nx}}x^{100}\,\dd x}
=
\color{#f00}{\expo{} - 1 \over 101}
$$