# Integration with Fractional Part (Calculus) $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int\limits_0^1{e^{\{nx\}}\cdot x^{2016}dx} $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int\limits_0^1{e^{\{nx\}}\cdot x^{2016}dx} = \text{ } ? $$

$\{nx\}$ - Fractional Part Number. Example: $\{-2/3\}=\{4/3\}=1/3$

**My solve:**
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{2017}}\int\limits_0^n{e^{\{t\}}\cdot t^{2016}dt} , t=nx$$

Please give me a clue what to do next

Comment: Well..seems that I just did some repeated work..see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847922

Comment: @Aforest Thank you! Sorry I could not find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^ne^{\{t\}} t^{2016}dt&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}e^{\{t\}} t^{2016}dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(t+k)^{2016}dt
\end{align}
$$

---

Then,
$$
\frac{1}{n^{2017}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(t+k)^{2016}dt=\frac{1}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(\frac t n+\frac k n)^{2016}dt\\
\frac{1}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(\frac k n)^{2016}dt\le \frac{1}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(\frac t n+\frac k n)^{2016}dt\le \frac{1}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(\frac {k+1} n)^{2016}dt
$$
From Riemann sum,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(\frac k n)^{2016}dt=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1e^t(\frac {k+1} n)^{2016}dt&=\int_0^1e^tdt\int_0^1x^{2016}dx\\&=\frac {e-1} {2017}
\end{align}